# Top.smallestPerKey() not working for sorting timestamp

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a use case where a PCollection contains key value pairs with the key being the user id and the value being the timestamp at which the user interacted with the application.

In the ETL purpose, I want to create a PCollection that contains key value pairs where key is the user id and value is the timestamp at which the user interacted with the application for the first time.

I am using the [Top.smallestPerKey()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Top.html#smallestPerKey-int-) transform for getting a PCollection of unique user ids and the earliest timestamp.

Code Snippet is the following -

```java
PCollection<KV<String, Timestamp>> keyedUserAndTimestamp =
    a.apply(ParDo.named("Getting minimum timestamp for a user.").of(
        new DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, Long>>(){
          @Override
          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            c.output(KV.of(
                c.element().get("user_id").toString(), 
                Timestamp.valueOf(c.element().get("time_stamp").toString())));
          }
        }));

PCollection<KV<String, List<Timestamp>>> minTimestampPerUser =
    keyedFromUserAndTimestamp.apply(Top.smallestPerKey(1));
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me. I am getting the following error -

```java
The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<KV<String,Long>>,OutputT>)
in the type PCollection<KV<String,Long>>
is not applicable for the arguments  
(PTransform<
     PCollection<KV<Object,Comparable<Comparable<V>>>>,
     PCollection<KV<Object,List<Comparable<Comparable<V>>>>>>)
```

I am new to Google cloud dataflow and Java, so I might also be missing on something very obvious.

Couple of questions I would like the community's insight on -

1. Is this the correct way of finding the minimum value of timestamp?
2. Am I using the correct transform? If not, what would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Java type error, not particularly specific to Dataflow. In this case, I believe you are being bitten by Java's type inference limitations and you must provide explicit type parameters to `Top.smallestPerKey`, specifically `Top.<String, Long>smallestPerKey(1)`.

Since you mention you are new to Java, I'll go into more detail. The signature of `Top.smallestPerKey` is:

```java
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>>
  PTransform<PCollection<KV<K, V>>, PCollection<KV<K, List<V>>>>
  smallestPerKey(int count)
```

where `K` and `V` are types determined when you call the function. Java has failed to infer what `K` and `V` ought to be for you. In this situation, Java falls back to the upper bounds on the types:

- `K` has no upper bound, so it is chosen to be `Object`.
- `V` has an upper bound of `Comparable<V>` (despite the seeming self-reference, this is a perfectly reasonable and common thing to do) so Java chooses `Comparable<V>`, even though `V` is not even a valid type in the context where your error message occurs.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped! Any comment on whether this is the right transform to use?

Comment: Yes, this is a perfect application of the transform.